# Get distinct column values from from first three columns and give priority to fourth column value SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the distinct column values from first three columns and fourth column contains tri-state values i,e. 1,0,Null and the fourth column value should be taken on the order above mentioned.

for eg if my table data is like

[image: Initial Data]

[image: Desired Output]

Where first three columns are grouped and fourth column values are given priority

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `MAX` With the `GroupBY` clause.

```
 SELECT
     Proj,
     sponser,
     Id,
     Max(visible) AS MaxVisible
 FROM
      tableName
 GROUP BY
   Proj,Sponser,Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT Proj,
       Sponsor,
       ID,
       Visible
FROM   (SELECT Proj,
               Sponsor,
               ID,
               Visible,
               Row_Number()
                 OVER(
                   Partition BY PRoj, Sponsor, ID
                   ORDER BY Visible DESC) AS RN
        FROM   #Yourtable)A
WHERE  RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to get the expected result, answer already posted are correct. I just wanted to display use of CTE to get the same result.

**BASED ON YOUR EXAMPLE**

Please find the queries as below to get the required output. Yes CTE will cost lesser then the nested queries.

```
CREATE TABLE  project (proj VARCHAR(5), Sponsor VARCHAR(5), ID INT, visible INT null) 

INSERT INTO project 
SELECT 'A', 'a', 123, NULL
UNION 
SELECT 'A', 'a', 123, 1
UNION 
SELECT 'A', 'a', 123, 0
UNION
SELECT 'B', 'b', 345, NULL
UNION 
SELECT 'B', 'b', 345, 1
UNION 
SELECT 'B', 'b', 345, 0
UNION
SELECT 'C', 'c', 567, 0
UNION 
SELECT 'D', 'd', 897, 0
UNION 
SELECT 'D', 'd', 897, 1
UNION 
SELECT 'E', 'e', 765, NULL 


;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT proj, Sponsor,ID,visible, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY proj ORDER BY visible DESC) AS Rank 
FROM project
) 
SELECT  proj, Sponsor,ID,visible 
FROM CTE 
WHERE Rank = 1
```